# Is it possible to read IE Session cookies?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am just wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to read Session Cookies of Internet Explorer. If the cookie has an expiry date it will be stored on disk. If the cookie has an expiry date of 0 then it will be stored in memory. My question is, is it possible to read the session cookies from the Internet Explorer processes memory? What Windows API's can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out WinINet functions and in particular InternetGetCookieEx function

Comment: It doesn't get session cookies.